# Optimizing AJAX requests for retrieving comments

Tags: php, ajax, performance, pagespeed

Hi i have a discussion page in PHP where there will be topics listed with comments below that. I'm loading all the topics during the page load and comments through ajax request. Since the user can add any number of topics and any number of comments under each topic, the page tooks very huge time to load(In case when 10 topics(paginated) and 100 comments under each topic). So how to optimize this for some great speed?  Any idea on this would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I'm sending a request for each topic

Comment: Can you add some code? and what languages are you using?

Comment: How are you loading comments right now? One request per comment? Per topic? Per user?

Comment: Cache it. Load data only when needed

Comment: @Passerby: Please see the note

Comment: @Udhay 10 requests shouldn't be a big problem in general. But anyway, I think the answer provided by Sam would be a good start: load first few, load more when users ask.

Answer (score 0):

Load some basic topics and a few comments during the initial page load, and then use AJAX to load more comments/topics when the user clicks on the respective links to load more. Check out the facebook updates as an example.